Average precision vs Average recall in object detection
There are two popular metrics for object detection: Average precision and Average recall. Do you can explain with examples, what are the cases to use AP, and what are the cases to use AR?
I agree that discrete metrics (with threshold) are bad, but the question is: why there are two metrics AP and AR, what is the difference between them?
To apply scoring rules I have to know the cost of misclassification. My particular task is object detection in autonomous driving, and it's not obvious how to assign this cost. Ultimately, I need to minimize the accident rate and maximize throughput, passenger comfort or some other subjective metric. Moreover, I would have to look at the autonomous vehicle as a whole (sensing, perception, planning, etc).
Additional thought - all object detection metrics, known for me, are discrete, because they include IOU (intersection over union).
At this point I want to know:

The difference between AP and AR, especially I have these metrics already implemented.
What proper metrics do I can use in my particular task? If you can suggest truly continuous metric without thresholds, I would be grateful to you.

I think this question is NOT a duplicate of "Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?"
This question is about difference between AP and AR.

Don't use either one. They suffer from the exact same issues as accuracy.

@StephanKolassa tried to clarify my question
